# Interfaces and instantiation

Tags: java

I have been reading a book on Java (Sams Teach Yourself Java in 21 Days 6th edition) and I have a question.

Book says,

> **Interfaces** cannot be **instantiated**: ***new*** can only create an instance of a **non-abstract** class.

Then it goes on and says a paragraph or so later that You can declare a variable to be of an interface type for eg.

```
Iterator loop = new Iterator();
```

Isn't that instantiating the interface as we are using `new`?

Comment: `new Iterator()` would be incorrect. Usually an object may have a method called `getIterator()`. Have you checked the errata?

Comment: If that is the only snippet and `Iterator` is referring to `java.util.Iterator`, then the book is posting wrong code.

Comment: You can instantiate classes that implement the interface. You cannot instantiate the interface directly. I notice they don't give the Iterator a generic type, how old is that book?

Comment: The code proves that - "You CANNOT learn Java in 21 DAYS". Say Away.

Comment: Does this help? it goes on and says "When a variable is declared to be of an interface type, it is an object that implements the interface. In this case,because loop is an object of the type Iterator, the assumption is that you can call all 3 of the interface's method on that object: hasNext(), Next(), remove()."

Comment: You can declare a variable to be of an interface type. the book said it correct. That next was a typo. It should have been `Iterator loop;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second declaration is wrong:

> Then it goes on and says a paragraph or so later that "You can declare a variable to be of an interface type for eg. `Iterator loop = new Iterator();"`

You indeed can declare variable `Iterator loop;`, you can initialize it using method that returns `Iterator`, constructor of class that implements `Iterator` or using anonymous inner class, however you cannot instatiate `Iterator` directly.

EDIT:

I found this book online. But the 5th adition. Here are the quotes:

> Remember that almost everywhere that you can use a class, you can use an interface instead. For example, you can declare a variable to be of an interface type:
>   Iterator loop = new Iterator() When a variable is declared to be of an interface type, it simply means that the object is expected to have implemented that interface. In this case, because Iterator contains an object of the type Iterator, the assumption is that you can call all three of the inter- face’s methods on that object: hasNext(), next(), and remove().

Fantastic! The book that has 6th edition contains so stupid mistake! Unbelievable...

Comment: Perhaps the author read - "How to write a book in 21 days" :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create instance of interface. What this book is referring to, is probably an anonymous inner class that *implements* given interface. For example, you can create a `Runnable`, like this:

```
Runnable instance = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      ...
   }
};
```

In case of `Iterator` interface, you'd have to implement all 3 methods defined there: `next()`, `hasNext()` and `remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two classes: "Circle" and "Rectangle" which implement the interface "Area" and define their own version of implemented methods getParams() and calculateArea(),

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Area area; //no direct instatiation
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    Circle circ = new Circle();
    area = rect;//assign as another object; indirect instantiation
    area.getParams();
    area.calculateArea();
    area = circ;
    area.getParams();
    area.calculateArea();
}
```

This code will work fine. Notice that the interface object area is created but not instantiated directly. It is later assigned as the object of the class which implemented it.